# Docker + WerckerCi: Tag not found

Tags: docker, wercker

Error:
`2945b19971bcc3626a0b96ee0edec5da16db05db not found in repository onitsoft/nexchange"`

From wercker run:

```
export WERCKER_STEP_ROOT="/pipeline/script-f4758b11-fd79-4526-8b0f-93abac20a880"
export WERCKER_STEP_ID="script-f4758b11-fd79-4526-8b0f-93abac20a880"
export WERCKER_STEP_OWNER="wercker"
export WERCKER_STEP_NAME="script"
export WERCKER_REPORT_NUMBERS_FILE="/report/script-f4758b11-fd79-4526-8b0f-93abac20a880/numbers.ini"
export WERCKER_REPORT_MESSAGE_FILE="/report/script-f4758b11-fd79-4526-8b0f-93abac20a880/message.txt"
export WERCKER_REPORT_ARTIFACTS_DIR="/report/script-f4758b11-fd79-4526-8b0f-93abac20a880/artifacts"
source "/pipeline/script-f4758b11-fd79-4526-8b0f-93abac20a880/run.sh" < /dev/null
Warning: Permanently added 'nexchange.co.uk,46.101.109.222' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-85-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Thu Jul 21 10:39:17 EDT 2016

  System load:  0.02               Processes:              79
  Usage of /:   90.0% of 19.56GB   Users logged in:        0
  Memory usage: 8%                 IP address for eth0:    46.101.109.222
  Swap usage:   0%                 IP address for docker0: 172.17.42.1

  => / is using 90.0% of 19.56GB

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

50 packages can be updated.
25 updates are security updates.

WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/wercker/.dockercfg.
Login Succeeded
2945b19971bcc3626a0b96ee0edec5da16db05db: Pulling from onitsoft/nexchange
5cd2fc295c2d: Pulling fs layer
8ebeee85900d: Already exists
42144437676a: Already exists
1fce3d4550ae: Already exists
bf1e607c2842: Already exists
52b692b39533: Already exists
1be0ba3ef303: Already exists
ae2720c39512: Already exists
0a0f2ba57426: Already exists
1f918a6cd980: Already exists
46d868b19364: Already exists
92cf95dd3c34: Already exists
a8a1579fd430: Already exists
b8a57c6e765a: Already exists
39820a3310c1: Already exists
7da5586e8893: Already exists
54586b8a57a3: Already exists
6ba35912dacf: Already exists
ff3863944b81: Already exists
7364542ca8a1: Already exists
5cd2fc295c2d: Verifying Checksum
5cd2fc295c2d: Download complete
Pulling repository onitsoft/nexchange
time="2016-07-21T10:39:48-04:00" level=fatal msg="Tag 2945b19971bcc3626a0b96ee0edec5da16db05db not found in repository onitsoft/nexchange" 
Unable to find image 'onitsoft/nexchange:2945b19971bcc3626a0b96ee0edec5da16db05db' locally
2945b19971bcc3626a0b96ee0edec5da16db05db: Pulling from onitsoft/nexchange
5cd2fc295c2d: Pulling fs layer
8ebeee85900d: Already exists
42144437676a: Already exists
1fce3d4550ae: Already exists
bf1e607c2842: Already exists
52b692b39533: Already exists
1be0ba3ef303: Already exists
ae2720c39512: Already exists
0a0f2ba57426: Already exists
1f918a6cd980: Already exists
46d868b19364: Already exists
92cf95dd3c34: Already exists
a8a1579fd430: Already exists
b8a57c6e765a: Already exists
39820a3310c1: Already exists
7da5586e8893: Already exists
54586b8a57a3: Already exists
6ba35912dacf: Already exists
ff3863944b81: Already exists
7364542ca8a1: Already exists
5cd2fc295c2d: Verifying Checksum
5cd2fc295c2d: Download complete
Pulling repository onitsoft/nexchange
time="2016-07-21T10:40:12-04:00" level=fatal msg="Tag 2945b19971bcc3626a0b96ee0edec5da16db05db not found in repository onitsoft/nexchange"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked  this and turns out that it's caused by a disk full. 
Docker has free space to start pulling the image but cannot finish it because disk gets full during the process, therefore the process fails and this *not so helpfull* message is returned.

free up some space on disk will solve this error, in this specific case.